# Is it possible to reload an image directly in the 3d view?

Tags: texturing, interface, 3d-view, image, shortcut

I am trying to reload the image i use to my 3d model directly in the 3d view. From what i can understand so far you can reload bu putting the mouse pointer over the material panel and pressing alt+R or press"reload current image from disk", however that is very frustrating to be forced to open that panel everytime,especially since i worked with maximized 3d view and my custom made pie menu, is it possible to write your own shortcut for this, or is it some kind of script that can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**An ugly method (but possibly enough for your needs)**
If you just have a few images and they aren't giant. You can reload all images, (The update becomes visible after moving 3dview around a little)

```
import bpy

bl_info = {
    "name": "Refresh Images",
    "version": (0, 1),
    "blender": (2, 76, 0),
    "description": "Refresh images",
    "category": "3D View"
}


class SimpleImageUpdater(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "view3d.refresh_images"
    bl_label = "Image Refresher"

    def execute(self, context):
        for img in bpy.data.images:
            img.reload()
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleImageUpdater)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleImageUpdater)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Auto updating version of the execute function

```
def execute(self, context):
    for img in bpy.data.images:
        img.reload()
    bpy.ops.wm.redraw_timer(type='DRAW_WIN_SWAP', iterations=1)
    return {'FINISHED'}
```

it should look like this: https://gist.github.com/zeffii/6189c3be154ad67f1592

Comment: Thanks Zeffi, Works Fantastic! As you say you have to move the model a bit but that is no problem what so ever, what a time saver!

Comment: code could be added to update 3dview, but it's cosmetic :)

Comment: Got it, is it hard to add just one button in any tab on the "t" panel? for this command? I am using a script that allows me to move all commands i use to my own tab, even thought i try to use no panels at all i always end up having the "t" panel open anyway, could you add that in the code, or maybe it's so simple even i can fix it?

Comment: I rarely use panels because of the spacebar search tool/menu. . In 3d view, press space, type in 'refresh'  or just 'refr' and it will auto suggest. - hit enter to execute this command. I find this faster than looking for a button.

Comment: or you could add a reference to the operator in the Pie menu. How to do that is a new - separate question - we like to keep questions to one topic on BSE. so people can find answers to dedicated topics.

Comment: added a link to the full code as a gist.